# How do i change the position of the origin of the coordinates of my canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

When I create my canvas (0,0) is in the top right. I need a Cartesian coordinate system with its origin in the bottom middle of the window. Is there a way to change the coordinate system? If not how do I make a new one with these characteristics?

Comment: There's nothing built-in, so you'll need to do coordinate transformations from your logical system to the canvas's manually. It can be done via matrices, so `numpy` might be a good option.

Comment: _"When I create my canvas (0,0) is in the top right. "_ - no, it's the top-left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a meshgrid.

For example see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

"meshgrid is very useful to evaluate functions on a grid."

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
>>> y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
>>> xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
>>> z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
>>> h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Or without using a meshgrid you could also use two vectors to index the image:

Assuming your canvas is saved in a variable `im` you can the two cartesian axis with the origin in the bottom middle and then use them to index the pixels of you image:

```
x = np.arange(minx, maxx, 1)
y = np.arange(0, maxy, 1)
```

where `minx` and `maxx` should be `-(im.shape[1] / 2)` and `(im.shape[1] / 2)` (assuming your canvas has even number of columns.

And finally get one coordinate e.g. `coord=(your_x, your_y)` from `im`:

```
im[np.where(y==coord[1])[0], np.where(x==coord[0])[0]]
```

Comment: @BryanOakley I probably misunderstood what OP meant by "my canvas"